# WPF add new Slider style cause XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, slider, styles

i found [this](http://www.wpfhelper.com/index.php/component/content/article/23-modern-ui-for-wpf/android-ui-for-wpf/25-wpf-slider-style-inspired-by-android) `slider` style that i want to add.

i added all the 3 styles inside my `Window.Resources` and also put in the first style the 2 templates:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
             Width="4" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,10"
            BorderThickness="2"
            BorderBrush="LightGray"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="4" />
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"  Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Right"
             Width="4" Margin="2,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Top" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
             Height="4" Margin="0,0,0,2" />
                        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10,0"
            BorderThickness="2"
            BorderBrush="LightGray"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="4" />
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"  Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="LightGray" Placement="Bottom"
             SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="4" Margin="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                            <Setter TargetName="TopTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="BottomTick" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSlider}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="21" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="104" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalSlider}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="outerBorder"
                        Background="#5534b4e3"
                        BorderBrush="#5534b4e3"
                        Height="26" Width="26" Opacity="1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="13"/>
                        <Border Name="innerBorder"
                        Background="#FF34b4e3"
                        BorderBrush="#FF34b4e3"
                        Height="10" Width="10" CornerRadius="5" Opacity="1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#BB34b4e3" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="Background" Value="#55ACACAC" />
                            <Setter TargetName="outerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#55ACACAC" />
                            <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="Width" Value="4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="Height" Value="4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="2" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyte" >
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusStyle" StrokeDashArray="4 4" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Fill="Transparent"
                       Stroke="#99029cc7" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

because i want to give all my application `sliders` the same look i removed the `x:key` from all except the `x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyte"` in the first style because in this case this line:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
```

I have error: The resource `MyFocusVisualStyte` could not be resolved.
And after add `slider`:

```
<Slider Margin="454,122,0,543" />
```

I can see in the designer this `slider`:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2ijcxd.jpg

but when ry to run my application i have `XamlParseException`:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Initialization of
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Slider' threw an exception.' Line number
>   '921' and line position '17'.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Second line: `MyFocusVisualSty>>t<<e`... Typo?

Comment: Ok, checked the link of the original source of the Style, and I see it's not your typo... But check the names, just in case!

Comment: @mot rer - Check for inner exception. It will tell you exact error with your XAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Styles reference other Styles and Templates via StaticResource: MyFocusVisualStyte (Typo? Shouldn't it be MyFocusVisualStyle?), SliderThumbStyle, SliderRepeatButtonStyle, HorizontalSlider, VerticalSlider...

All these Styles and Templates must exist and be defined BEFORE they're used.

In this case, the resources must be defined in this order (I'll copy only the first node of each, and the parts where other Styles or Templates are referenced, to explain why the order is important):

First, FocusVisual Style, Thumb Style and the RepeatButton Style. These Styles have no reference to other resources, so they're safe to be defined first:

```
<Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyte" >
    ...

<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    ...

<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    ...
```

Then, the Horizontal and Vertical Slider Templates. The RepeatButtons and Thumbs inside use the Styles above, so they must be defined after those:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    ...
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"
                          Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"
                          Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
    ...

<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    ...
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"
                          Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" />
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"
                          Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
    ...
```

And finally, the Slider Style itself, that references these two Templates (and the FocusVisual Style). You can leave this one without the x:Key, so all your Sliders use the Style by default:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
    ...
    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSlider}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalSlider}" />
    </Trigger>
    ...
```

Comment: Wow I am so confused by the whole thing's style ! can get a code example how this should looks like ? (i want all my slider will be with the same look)

Comment: I think your problem is that you removed the `x:Key` of the `RepeatButton` and `Thumb` styles. That's breaking the Styles. It's probably safe to remove it from the `Slider` Style, though, and chances are that's enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: If you pay attention, you'll see that the x:Keys you removed (`SliderRepeatButtonStyle`, for instance) are being used by other Templates. Those references (via StaticResource) don't work now, and throw the Exception.

Comment: Also, the order in which Styles and Templates are defined is important. If Style X uses Template Y, then Y must be defined first in the code. In this case, the order would be somewhat inverse of how it's shown in the website: FocusVisual Style > Thumb Style > RepeatButton Style > Horizontal and Vertical Slider Templates > and finally the Slider Style.

Comment: i add this keys back, where i need to put the last style ? (FocusVisualStyte) because i can see that in the x:Key="SliderStyle" style The resource MyFocusVisualStyte could not be resolved

Comment: Put it above everything else, since it doesn't have any reference to any other Style or Template.

Comment: BTW how can i add the tick on the slider ?

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.tickplacement(v=vs.110).aspx ... You have to set the `TickPlacement` property of the `Slider`. You can play also with the `Ticks` and `TickFrequency` properties to change how many ticks must appear in the track.